# Where did the "paler skin means higher status" concept originate? And approximately when?

Tags: science-based, culture, alternate-history, history, ancient-history

I have observed the phenomenon of people with paler skin being seen as higher status and more desirable in a number of places where I have travelled, including SE Asia, India, Western Europe and its colonies (although toned down a bit by the human rights movement in recent decades) ...

I want to create a realistic alternative world without this concept, and I need to know how far back the changes would start. I have read as much as I can find about the early origins of civilisation, and I can't pinpoint where this idea originated, and why it became so prevalent.

Please, no explanations of how it spread after the Age of Discovery - I have read Guns, Germs and Steel, etc.

I am asking about the origins, before Western Europeans colonised everything. For example, the pale-skinned Aryans were the dominant caste in India by 1500 BC, and the pale-skinned Pharaohs in Egypt possibly even earlier, so it could have been at least 5000 years ago that this phenomenon began. Both these groups also had a taboo against marrying "out", which is why they come to mind as possible origin points.

It wasn't universal, so where did it come from?

Was it a single point of origin, or did it arise independently in multiple places?

Does anyone have any leads?

Comment: First, this is more a History SE question than here. Second, you list two instances that coincide with the dawn of writing in their respective regions. Since you can't tell skin color archaeologically, all we can do is to depend on what ancient writers said about the topic. I will say, that my understanding of history is that higher status goes to the higher civilization, which has often been lighter skinned by now always. The Greeks and Romans noted the pale skin of their 'barbarians'; Arabs valued the relative rarity of both black skinned and blond haired/blue eyed slaves.

Comment: if you belonged to "worker class" and have to work all day in the fields, you will get tanned skin color. On the other hand, people of certain status and wealth, spend their days mostly inside the walls. So, whiter skin color. Not to mention few (on none) marks due to accidents.

Comment: For certain the ancient world _did not_ associate paler skin with higher status. Roman historians are mostly race-blind, but some of the few occasions when they express what could be perceived as racial stereotypes is when they describe barbarians (such as the Cimbri) as having astonishingly white skin. The ancient Greeks and Romans thought that the "right" skin tone was not too dark and not too light. Which is to say, it depends and varies from culture to culture, and is quite often complicated by sexual stereotypes (dark men are desirable, light skinned women are desirable, for example).

Comment: @AlexP, the Greeks and Romans might not have, but the Indus Valley civilisation definitely did.

Comment: @kingledion, the Aryans had writing before 3000BC, long before they became the dominant ethnic group in Northern India.

Comment: Sorry Jnani, you have to ask it in history.SE - here we make fictional worlds viable (or semi-fictional). @kingledion has a point.

Comment: That just isn't true. I'd like to see some sort of reference for that. The Indus Valley Civilization (not Aryan) had some sort of proto-writing, but it is undeciphered at best, and possibly not real writing at worst. The earliest writing in the Aryan/Sanskrit tradition is the Rig Veda, variously dated 1700-1000 BC.

Comment: @Mindwin I am asking because I want to create a realistic alternative world without this concept.

Comment: Then you worded your question wrong. Edit it to reflect your real need.

Comment: @kingledion, that's a good point. The relationship between the Indus Valley script and later ones (Devanagari, Brahmi, etc) is "uncertain".  According to this author, the Vedic culture didn't have writing at that time. http://www.ancient.eu/Indus_Script/

Comment: @kingledion However, the Aryan people were mixing with the locals in that region from 5000BC. I still want to know how it is that the (vastly more numberous) locals ended up as the Untouchables by the time the Rig Veda was written.

Comment: It could be a very ancient hold over from homo sapiens interacting with neanderthals. Neanderthals where stronger, but sapiens were more adaptable. They could fashion better stone tools and therefore any trade that may have occurred between the groups (I'm sure there was trade...there was sex) could be that items made by homo sapiens where considered better value. But that is going waaayyyyyy way back.

Answer (score 3):

In higher civilizations low class people had to fulfill physical work often in the outside, thus being in the sun all day tanning their skin. On the contrary high class people often stayed inside their houses doing more management work and a lot of delegating physical work to their subjects, hence the brighter skin due to a lack of exposure to the sun. That's also where the term blue-blooded originates from, the blue veins shimmer through the untanned skin.

Personally I thought this philosophy originated in medieval europe but the concept could be easily transferred to earlier civilizations. As far as I know this has been the idea inside europe's civilization as well, which weakens the argument of caucasians conquering and colonizing the world as the main reason. No doubt, though, colonization did play a role in many non-european cultures but as said, later on in history.

Answer (score 2):

In both your examples, i.e., India and Egypt, skin colour being associated with caste is due to ... colonization. [Indo-Europeans (Arya) invaded the subcontinent through Persia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Indo-Aryan_migration&redirect=no) and pushed the darker skinned original inhabitants south. Skin colour as obvious distinction between new overlords and oppressed underclass, upper classes not having to work under the tropical sun, etc., etc., you get the picture.
In the case of Egypt, it was Alexander, whose general [Ptolemy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemy_I_Soter) eventually founded the last dynasty of Pharaohs that survived till Roman times.

Comment: Would you say that it is pure historical accident that these were pale-skinned people? Would the solution be as simple as making the Indo-Europeans dark-skinned from the dawn of time? It doesn't fit as well with the "peasants working in the sun" aspect, though.

Comment: @JnaniJennyHale : Not at all. They're lighter skinned because they came from a place with comparatively less sunlight. They came from a place with comparatively less sunlight, because the land couldn't sustain that many people, due to, again, low sunlight, which meant the growing season is shorter and winters were harsher and longer....and because they lost to their neighbours, who had the same problems, but were able to grab our "lighter-skinned invaders'" land. Basically, they wanted the land more than the locals and were more desperate to get it....

Comment: @JnaniJennyHale : ...contd. The locals had fights too, and plenty of darker skinned people have conquered other darker skinned people, they just didn't have obvious distinctions between them. As regards the other obvious question: "why didn't darker skinned people conquer lighter skinned peoples' land?", why would they? Central Asia's dry grassland, very poor for crops, and, other than the Mediterranean belt, most of Europe was wilderness with horrible winters and lots of wolves, accessible only over 3 mountain ranges or by sea. Not worth the expense of developing, even for the Romans.

Answer (score 0):

Lighter skin suggested a European relative such people usually have some sort of family connections to Europe. This gave them advantage when trying to rise in social status. 
 In addition to this I was already of high social status or more likely to intermingle and therefore breed with Europeans.

Lastly those who had European relatives were more likely to speak English and may have even been educated in the West this made it easier for them to trade with Europeansome. And it made them the more likely choice for leadership since in a leader would inevitably have to deal with the Europeans.

As for before the Europeans I can't speak for all the country but I remember reading that many of the lighter skin people in India descended from a group of invaders that came long before the European. They established Indias infamous cast system. They were naturally the highest class.big can't remember there people name right now but I will look it up later and post it in my answer.

Comment: Good points, but I think this answer focuses on too recent history, say last couple hundred years. I believe the OP is asking when did this first start, thousands of years ago.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @Bryan, but I am asking about the time BEFORE European colonisation and BEFORE the English language became the lingua franca (language of international trade).

Comment: I sorry let me edit